# In Python how do you apply a function to lists within a list?

Tags: python, list, function

In Python, If I have a list like

```
a = [[1,2,4],[4,3,1],[3,2,1]]
```

how would I apply a function to each list (for example sort each of the three lists individually)?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're having trouble.  You posted a list of lists, but call it an array.  Applying a function to a series of items is the well-documented `map` function -- but had you wanted that, your research before posting should have brought that up.  Please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

If the function returns a value that you want to keep, use a list comprehension, e.g.:

```
[sorted(sublist) for sublist in a]
```

If the function mutates the list in place and returns `None`, use a for-loop, e.g.:

```
for sublist in a:
    sublist.sort()
```

If the function returns a value that you want to keep, *and* it mutates the list, try to rewrite it to do just one or the other - perhaps separating it into two separate functions if necessary.

If the function returns a value that you want to keep, and it mutates the list, and you can't rewrite it to do just one or the other, then use a list comprehension and slap the author of this code with a wet fish<sup>†</sup>.

<sup>†</sup><sub>*Disclaimer*: If the author is your superior, the [fish slap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhJQp-q1Y1s) part is optional.</sub>

Comment: Great answer, except that no one who writes Python code that mutates and returns self is actually superior to a novice, no matter what management thinks, so I think the fish slap is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[[1,2,4],[4,3,1],[3,2,1]] 
for list in a:
    #apply func here example function(list), for sorting a list use list.sort()
    list.sort()
print(a)
```

```
[pc@pc-pc PasivicSoftware]$ python3.7 test.py
[[1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]]
```